# Laravel migrations error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run `php artisan migrate` i get error B

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'categories' already
>   exists'

What is it? Why? How to find error?
My categories migrations file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CategoriesTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('title')->index();
            $table->text('description');

            $table->integer('attachment_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('attachment_id')->references('id')->on('attachment')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like that table already exists in your DB.. have you checked that it doesn't?

Comment: even if I delete the table, the error remains. is not the case

Comment: How are you deleting the table?  Seems like you haven't defined the `down()` method in your migration file, so artisan won't delete that table

Comment: check your database config file and which database is used.

Comment: some of my migration triggered and tables are created. but not all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 Error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already)

Answer (score 0):

In that migration file, the function drop() should be

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('categories');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to create existing table..

so i think you are editing the migration file that you already installed

you can drop your database and re-migrate it

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```