# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Why I can not drop the table

Tags: laravel, migration, schema

In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'credit_prop_fees' already exists (SQL: create table `credit_prop_fees` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `fee_id` int not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at`
  timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

I have two migrations one by another few
This is firs one

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('credit_prop_fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('fee_id');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

As you see in the next migration I have dropeIfExist() function

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('credit_prop_fees');

        Schema::create('credit_prop_fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('credit_id');
            $table->integer('credit_prop_id');
            $table->integer('fee_type_id');
            $table->integer('fee_value_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I am trying to make php artisan migrate
Why I receive this error if I write Schema::dropIfExists('credit_prop_fees');

Even When I use tinker I have null but the table deleted
C:\OSPanel\domains\laravel.bai.loc>php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.12 — cli) by Justin Hileman

> > > Schema::drop('credit_prop_fees');
> > >       => null

Thanks for your answers

Comment: why you are using two scema for same table and schema drop on your up method??

Comment: If you try to run "php artisan migrate:status", is your second migration AFTER the first one? The first migration may be running after the second one, therefore not trying to drop the table.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are dropping new created table, But try :

```
php arisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: the same effect

Answer (score 0):

Same to me, I solved it by :
Use !Schema::hasTable('credit_prop_fees'), it will check whether a table already exists in the database or not.

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('credit_prop_fees')) {
    Schema::create('credit_prop_fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('credit_id');
            $table->integer('credit_prop_id');
            $table->integer('fee_type_id');
            $table->integer('fee_value_id');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Reference of answer is here:

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is php artisan migrate:fresh not php arisan migrate:fresh.