# My Laravel 5.3 Migrations seem to be messed up - how to fix?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 5.3 site and I suspect I made some manual database changes without using the Laravel migrate functionality and now it is biting me...

Now I am trying to get to a stable database situation.

Here was my migrations folder yesterday:

```
create_sometable1_table
create_sometable2_table
create_sometable3_table
```

And so on.

Then I added via

```
php artisan make:migration create_newtable_table
```

But later renamed the migration file and the model file to create_newtabledifferentname_table

Then I tried to add another table using

`php artisan make:migration create_anothertable_table`

But I get

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                       
  A CreateAnothertableTable migration already exists.
```

I ran the usual commands to try and get things into normal state, like `cache:clear`, and the recommended composer commands (like autoload).

But nothing works.

In my DB these tables don't exist and the migration file `create_anothertable_table` doesn't exist.

So I ran

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

And this resulted in all but 3 of my tables disappearing, with 3 now remaining in the database. The 3 remaining ones are not the ones of interest.

Anyway, I have all my tables and data on my live site and am just trying to get things locally looking the same, so no big deal that my DB on localhost is currently messed up.

Just need to know, how to get things into a stable state from this point onward?

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: there is a migration table in your database check there is ```create_anothertable_table``` or not

Comment: When you renamed the migration file, did you also change the class name inside the file?

Comment: Try doing php artisan migrate:fresh. Caution: it will empty all the db schema

Comment: Realized I didn't change the class name, looking into everything now! But what is still odd is that yesterday when I ran the migration create command even though it returned with no error the table was never created.

Comment: Ok, I tried to get things starting from fresh so followed some steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129270/laravel-5-5-error-base-table-or-view-already-exists-1050-table-users-already/47326189.